# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, sqlsrv

I get the error
`[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.` with the latest version of doctrine.

**Database Connection Code**

```php
$Params = [
    'dbname' => 'XXX',
    'user' => 'XXX',
    'password' => 'XXX',
    'host' => 'XXXX',
    'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'Encrypt' => 0,
    'TrustServerCertificate' => 1,
];
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($Params);
```

**Query**

```php
$queryBuilder = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder
    ->select('*')
    ->from('Job, JobDetail, JobStateChronic')
    ->where('Job.JobDetailID = JobDetail.JobDetailID AND Job.JobDetailID = JobStateChronic.JobDetailID')
    ->andWhere('YEAR(Job.StartDate) = ? AND MONTH(Job.StartDate) = ? AND DAY(Job.StartDate) = ?')
    ->setParameter(0, '2023')
    ->setParameter(1, '04')
    ->setParameter(3, '24')

;
$stm = $queryBuilder->executeQuery();
$data = $stm->fetchAllAssociative();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

I use Wampserver 3.3.1 as my web server.
It was working fine before i updated my php version from 8.2.0 to 8.2.9

This is the full error

```
[05.08.2023 - 12:10:49] [ERROR] [Uncaught Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.  SQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722" at C:\wamp64\www\taxihof-manager\vendor\doctrine\dbal\src\Driver\API\SQLSrv\ExceptionConverter.php line 67] {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\DriverException(code: -2146893019): An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n\nSQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722 at C:\\wamp64\\www\\taxihof-manager\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\src\\Driver\\API\\SQLSrv\\ExceptionConverter.php:67)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\SQLSrv\\Exception\\Error(code: -2146893019): SQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.\r\n\nSQLSTATE [08001, -2146893019]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection. For solutions related to encryption errors, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2226722 at C:\\wamp64\\www\\taxihof-manager\\vendor\\doctrine\\dbal\\src\\Driver\\SQLSrv\\Exception\\Error.php:42)"} []
```

I tried to use `TrustServerCertificate` with `Encrypt` which was working fine before.

Comment: not recommended but on your mysql server set require_secure_transport to OFF in the mysql configuration

Comment: MySQL isn't SQL Server, @DeanVanGreunen .

Comment: This sounds like you aren't passing the trust or encrypt parameter, if I am honest, as that's the error you get when you encrypt and and the cert isn't trusted (such as when it's the default self signed certificate).

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. My SQL Server was using V17 and i installed ODBC Driver 18 on my PC. It worked after installing ODBC Driver 17 on my PC.

Comment: This likely cements my point. ODBC brough encrypted by default so it seems you weren't actually setting the trust of the cert. Downgrading isn't really the solution, it just kicks the can down the road.